# .htaccess mod rewrite regex to not match file names

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am using the following .htaccess configuration directives (to redirect all non filename requests to a single PHP file):

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule !(\.ttf|\.eot|\.woff|\.xpi|\.xml|\.txt|\.air|\.exe|\.zip|\.pdf|\.ico|\.gif|\.jpg|\.png|\.jpeg|\.js|\.swf|\.css|\.php|\.html)$ mod_rewrite_redirector.php [L]
```

**How can I make the above regex case insensitive?** I have tried [L,NC] or placing (?i) at the beggining. NC option doesn't work on all Apache2 installations (various versions) and (?i) has no effect.

**How can I make a regex which will *not* match URLS which look like a filename with an extension between 2 and 4 characters?**

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
RewriteRule !\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4}$ mod_rewrite_redirector.php [L]
```

But if you want to redirect requests to files that does not exists on your server, it is better to use :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . mod_rewrite_redirector.php [L]
```

Comment: I didn't mention I have already tried `RewriteRule !\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4}$ mod_rewrite_redirector.php [L]` because I tought I did something wrong. It is not working. URLs such as `/images/Myself.png` still get redirected to `mod_rewrite_redirector.php`.

Comment: Scratch the above, it is working. I was facing a non-related issue: I was relying for a folder on defaulting to index.html, which was not happening because of the mod rewrite. I had to specify the complete path.